# iOS : How to get image with specific size from AssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, assetslibrary

I am in trouble with my App and expecting your help. I want to upload photo with specific size**(1200*1800)** from library to server,and I need to get original image then compress it.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset fullResolutionImage] scale:[asset scale] orientation:0];
```

Unfortunately my app will get crashed if the original image size is large than **20M**. So is there any way to get the image with specific size from AssetsLibrary directly?

Comment: Why don't you inspect the image's byte size before loading it into memory?

Comment: I need to get orignal image then use it to resize.

Answer (score 1):

I just Put some Helpful code, i am not sure but might be helpful in your case:

**For Get Crop Image:**

```
UIImage *croppedImg = nil;
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(AS YOu Need);
croppedImg = [self croppIngimageByImageName:self.imageView.image toRect:cropRect];
```

Use following method that return `UIImage` (*as You want size of image*)

```
- (UIImage *)croppIngimageByImageName:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        //CGRect CropRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height+15);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
        UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

        return cropped;
    }
```

Here you get Croped Image that return by above method;

**OR RESIZING**

And also Use following method for specific **hight** and **width** with **image** for **Resizing UIImage**:

```
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This method return **NewImage**, with specific size that you want.

Comment: But how can I get original image(imageToCrop or image)? If it's size is too large, my app will receive low memory warning and get crashed when I get original image from AssetsLibrary.